# pytest: assert almost equal

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, assert

How to do `assert almost equal` with `pytest` for floats without resorting to something like:

```
assert x - 0.00001 <= y <= x + 0.00001
```

More specifically it will be useful to know a neat solution for quickly comparing pairs of float, without unpacking them:

```
assert (1.32, 2.4) == i_return_tuple_of_two_floats()
```

Comment: py.test now has a feature that does this.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39623614/5353461) for a description of that feature

Answer (score 515, accepted):

I noticed that this question specifically asked about pytest. pytest 3.0 includes an [`approx()` function](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html?highlight=approx#pytest.approx) (well, really class) that is very useful for this purpose.

```py
import pytest

assert 2.2 == pytest.approx(2.3)
# fails, default is ± 2.3e-06
assert 2.2 == pytest.approx(2.3, 0.1)
# passes

# also works the other way, in case you were worried:
assert pytest.approx(2.3, 0.1) == 2.2
# passes
```

Comment: Nice! Also found it works for sequences of numbers too e.g. `assert [0.1 + 0.2, 0.2 + 0.4] == pytest.approx([0.3, 0.6])`

Comment: @Mr Kriss And even for dicts: `assert {'a': 0.1+0.2} == pytest.approx({'a': 0.3})`

Comment: This doesn't work for lists of lists: for example, `assert [[0.1 + 0.2], [0.2 + 0.4]] == pytest.approx([[0.3], [0.6]])` leads to a `TypeError`. If found that Numpy's `np.testing.assert_allclose([[0.1 + 0.2], [0.2 + 0.4]], [[0.3], [0.6]])` (see answer below) did work for this case.

Comment: It's worth noting that the second positional argument is relative tolerance, but you can specify absolute tolerance as well:
`0.2 == pytest.approx(0.3, 0.1) # returns false; 0.2 == pytest.approx(0.3, abs=0.1) # returns true`

Comment: I do believe it is [now] a function. `def approx(expected, rel=None, abs=None, nan_ok: bool = False) -> ApproxBase:`

Answer (score 58):

You will have to specify what is "almost" for you:

```
assert abs(x-y) < 0.0001
```

to apply to tuples (or any sequence):

```
def almost_equal(x,y,threshold=0.0001):
  return abs(x-y) < threshold

assert all(map(almost_equal, zip((1.32, 2.4), i_return_tuple_of_two_floats())
```

**Update:**
[`pytest.approx`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.approx) was released as part of [`pytest v3.0.0`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/changelog.html#release-3-0-0) in 2016.
This answer predates it, use this if:

- you don't have a recent version of `pytest` AND
- you understand floating point precision and it's impact to your use case.

for practically all common scenarios, use
`pytest.approx` as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39623614/249878) answer.

Comment: The question asks how to do it "without resorting to something like" this

Comment: I interpret "something like this" as a repetitive and awkward expression like `x - d <= y <= x+d`, seems like that's what OP meant as well. If you don't wish to explicitly specify the threshold for 'almost', see @jiffyclub's answer.

Comment: py.test now has a feature that does this. I've added an answer discussing it.

Comment: @NeilG Why on earth should this be deleted?  If there's something obviously wrong with it please explain what it is.

Comment: @user2699 The question is how to do this in pytest.  The correct way to do it in pytest is to to use `pytest.approx`.  Writing your own approximate function is a bad idea.  (The one in this answer isn't even as good as the included one.)

Comment: @NeilG, Sure, but `pytest.approx` didn't exist when this answer was posted, and probably does the exact same thing under the hood.

Comment: @user2699 that's why this answer is no longer up to date. It's not actually what happens under the hood (there's a lot more). And anyway, no one should be reinventing what's already in pytest.

Comment: @yurib This is a repetitive and akward expression. Though I love using built-in functions like `all`, `map`, and `zip`, in this case it's very long and doesn't read well.

Comment: @pigrammer there's zero repetition in this expression. and it's long and doesn't read well because it uses names from the original question and readability is subjective. you're a developer - make it readable for you.... `def myapprox(left, right): return all(map(approx, zip(left,right)))`.

Answer (score 41):

If you have access to NumPy it has great functions for floating point comparison that already do pairwise comparison with [`numpy.testing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.testing.html).

Then you can do something like:

```
numpy.testing.assert_allclose(i_return_tuple_of_two_floats(), (1.32, 2.4))
```

Answer (score 21):

These answers have been around for a long time, but I think the easiest and also most readable way is to use unittest for it's [many nice assertions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.html#assert-methods) without using it for the testing structure.

## Get assertions, ignore rest of unittest.TestCase

(based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18084492/377366))

```
import unittest

assertions = unittest.TestCase('__init__')
```

## Make some assertions

```
x = 0.00000001
assertions.assertAlmostEqual(x, 0)  # pass
assertions.assertEqual(x, 0)  # fail
# AssertionError: 1e-08 != 0
```

## Implement original questions' auto-unpacking test

Just use * to unpack your return value without needing to introduce new names.

```
i_return_tuple_of_two_floats = lambda: (1.32, 2.4)
assertions.assertAlmostEqual(*i_return_tuple_of_two_floats())  # fail
# AssertionError: 1.32 != 2.4 within 7 places
```

Comment: This has the advantage to every answer above that you can use collections and assert them to be equal +1

Answer (score 16):

If you want something that works not only with floats but for example Decimals you can use python's [math.isclose()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose):

```py
# - rel_tol=0.01` is 1% difference tolerance.
assert math.isclose(actual_value, expected_value, rel_tol=0.01)
```

Comment: Here relative tolerance (or percentage difference) is convenient to use in some use cases, e.g. scienfific.

Answer (score 14):

Something like

```
assert round(x-y, 5) == 0
```

That is what [unittest](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertAlmostEqual) does

For the second part

```
assert all(round(x-y, 5) == 0 for x,y in zip((1.32, 2.4), i_return_tuple_of_two_floats()))
```

Probably better to wrap that in a function

```
def tuples_of_floats_are_almost_equal(X, Y):
    return all(round(x-y, 5) == 0 for x,y in zip(X, Y))

assert tuples_of_floats_are_almost_equal((1.32, 2.4), i_return_tuple_of_two_floats())
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd use nose.tools. It plays well with py.test runner and have other equally useful asserts - assert_dict_equal(), assert_list_equal(), etc.

```
from nose.tools import assert_almost_equals
assert_almost_equals(x, y, places=7) #default is 7
```

Comment: Besides pytest has an option for this I don't consider a good option add an extra depency (in this case, a whole testing framwork) only for this.

Answer (score 0):

Could just use round()

```
a, b = i_return_tuple_of_two_floats()
assert (1.32, 2.4) == round(a,2), round(b,1)
```