# Is there a way to use Python unit test assertions outside of a TestCase?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I need to create a fake helper class to be used in unit tests (injected into tested classes). Is there some way to use TestCase assertions in such class?

I would like to use the assertions for some common checks performed by the Fake class. Something like:

```
class FakeFoo(object):

  def do_foo(self, a, b):
    assertNotNull(a)
    ...
```

Comment: Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5142453/758446

Comment: Built-in assert would work if there is no other way, but TestCase assertions are more verbose and have few advantages over the built-in: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2958169/1031601

Comment: You are right; I wanted to give a reference that would put some of that in perspective.  I wasn't proposing such as a solution.  Thanks for the second link. :)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can create a instance of `unittest.TestCase()` and call the methods on that.

```
import unittest

tc = unittest.TestCase()
tc.assertIsNotNone(a)
```

On older Python versions (Python 2.7 and earlier, 3.0, 3.1) you need to you pass in the name of an *existing* method on the class `TestCase` class (normally it's passed the name of a test method on a subclass). `__init__` will do in this case:

```
tc = unittest.TestCase('__init__')
tc.assertIsNotNone(a)
```

However, you are probably looking for a good [Mock library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) instead. [`mock`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) would be a good choice.

Another option is to use `pytest`, which [augments `assert` statements](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#assert) to provide the same or more context as `unittest.TestCase()` assertion methods; you'd simply write `assert a is not None`.

Comment: Since Python 3.2 you don't need to pass anything in the constructor. [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase): "Changed in version 3.2: TestCase can be instantiated successfully without providing a methodName. This makes it easier to experiment with TestCase from the interactive interpreter."

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pytest or Nosetest. Though I'don't know if they have 'assertNotNull' function. I know they can use 'assert' simply for assertion. Or you can use something like assertpy or ptest, if you like, you can search for them on github.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question, and add e.g. some links and a bit of more explanations.