# Assert two variables are almost equal in python

Tags: python, python-unittest

Here are two variables: `earnings_forecast`, `actual_earning` (numerical variables)

I want to assert if both these variables are equal with a difference of ±2% acceptable with respect to `actual_earning` variable.

Suppose:
`earnings_forecast = 6`
`actual_earnings = 5.19`

I cannot use `assertEqual(earnings_forecast, actual_earnings)` because it will try do an exact match, instead I want to assert both these variables are almost equal with ±2% difference acceptable.

Comment: Two percent of which? Anyway just calculate the difference and assert its absolute value is smaller than the number you want.

Comment: Are these numerical values, or just any objects?

Comment: Implement your own `compare` function that will return `True` or `False` and use the `unittest` built-in `assertTrue` (given that the built-in `assertAlmostEqual` won't be of help in this case).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use Python unit test assertions outside of a TestCase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084476/is-there-a-way-to-use-python-unit-test-assertions-outside-of-a-testcase)

Comment: Assert two values `tc = unittest.TestCase('__init__')

tc.assertEqual(a,b)` [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18084492/452708)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the new isclose function introduced in Python 3.5

> PEP 485 adds the math.isclose() and cmath.isclose() functions which
>   tell whether two values are approximately equal or “close” to each
>   other. Whether or not two values are considered close is determined
>   according to given absolute and relative tolerances. Relative
>   tolerance is the maximum allowed difference between isclose arguments,
>   relative to the larger absolute value

```
import math
a = 100.0
b = 102.0
c = 103.0

assert math.isclose(a,b, rel_tol=0.02)
assert math.isclose(a,c, rel_tol=0.02)
```

Comment: Oh that's posh. Scrap my way.

Comment: equivalent to `abs(a-b) <= max( rel_tol * max(abs(a), abs(b)), abs_tol )`

Comment: Numpy also has a similar implementation of this: [`numpy.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) and an array-based equivalent [`numpy.allclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html#numpy.allclose) which can increase performance for large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

```
abs(earnings_forecast - actual_earning) < 0.01 * abs(earnings_forecast + actual_earning)
```

is a nice way of doing it, which gives you a good symmetric 2% difference on either side. It also doesn't suffer from pitfalls that can arise of one of the values is zero.

There are other definitions, but like the one above, they have their own pros and cons.

Comment: @schwobaseggl: only if they are complex numbers ;-) Note the sign.

Comment: @schwobaseggl: touche.

Comment: Looks inconsistent. With a forcast of 100, an actual earning of 98 results in `False` but an actual earning of 102 results in `True`, even though they're both exactly 2% away from 100.

Comment: Yup. It does have curiosities, but then other schemes will too.

Answer (score 1):

Simply define a new test:

```
def assertNearlyEqual(self,a,b,fraction=0.02,msg=None):
    if abs(a-b) > abs(fraction*a):
        if msg is None:
            self.fail("The given numbers %s and %s are not near each other."%(a,b))
        else:
            fail(msg)
```

and call it with your two variables:

```
self.assertNearlyEqual(earnings_forecast,actual_earning)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach:

```
a, b = sorted(map(float, (a, b)))
assert a + abs(a)*1.02 >= b
```

You can use a custom `Testcase` subclass for use in tests:

```
class FooTestCase(TestCase):
    def assertAlmostEqual(a, b):
        a, b = sorted(map(float, (a, b)))
        self.assertTrue(a + abs(a)*1.02 >= b)
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who still use Python 2.x, you could also use [numpy.isclose()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html)

```
from numpy import isclose as isclose
a = 100.0
b = 100.01

print isclose(a,b, atol=0.02)  # True
```

From the documentation:

> For finite values, isclose uses the following equation to test whether
>   two floating point values are equivalent.
>
> ```
> absolute(a - b) <= (atol + rtol * absolute(b))
> ```