# How to assert values are equal in selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium

i pass coordinates -40 and -40 to a method like below
and the robot test is as below

```
Test something
    asset_something -40 -40
```

So in the above statement -40 and -40 are treated as strings.

```
assert_something (-40, -40) {
    xcoord = (location['x'] + element.size['width'] /2) - 
    (canvas.location['x'] + canvas.size['width'] / 2)
    ycoord = (location['y'] + element.size['height'] /2) 
    (canvas.location['y'] + canvas.size['height'] // 2)
    assert xcoord == -40
    assert ycoord == -40
}
```

Here in the above method the value of xcoord and ycoord is -40.0 so i get an assertion error since i am comparing -40.0 to -40

how can do the assertion that both are equal..i tried below

```
xcoord = int(location['x'] + element.size['width'] /2) - (canvas.location['x'] + 
    canvas.size['width'] 
    / 2)
    ycoord = int(location['y'] + element.size['height'] /2) - (canvas.location['y'] + 
    canvas.size['height'] // 2)
```

but it was converting only ycoord to -40 but xcoord value remained to be -40.0 how can i fix this. thanks.

Comment: `-40.0 == -40` should evaluate to `True`

Comment: yes but it gives assertion error not sure why

Comment: please check the type(xcoord) and type(ycoord).

Comment: typeofx <class 'float'>
typeofy <class 'float'>  they are float values

Comment: typeox <class 'str'>
typeofy <class 'str'> these values that i pass to the method are treated as strings.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41808286/assert-two-variables-are-almost-equal-in-python) and use a small delta and see if that works.